# Apart from affecting the bundling in the global.asax is there any way to manually add script and css on razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When mvc3 was created I placed one of these on my _layout.cshtml page...

```
@Html.RenderCss()
@Html.RenderScript()
```

Then in my inheriting razor pages I did this...

```
@Html.RegisterScript("~/Content/scripts/myscript.js")
```

Is there now an automatic way to do this with the optimisation dlls that. I dont really want to bundle everything in the folder all the time. Id also like it to minify the file too automatically. Not sure if im missing the point of this bundling feature but i just want to add files dynamically and then have them render out all at the same place on the page...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the bundling feature, which is still pre-release and somewhat buggy is that it is designed to combine and then minify all of your CSS or JS files you might need in your project.  It then uses a versioning mechanism so that clients get the full browser caching experience.

For example if I have 3 CSS files (Reset.css, Global.css, and Site.css) these all get downloaded on the first visit to my site, they are combined and minified so the file size is quite small.  The url contains a special hash number/querystring.  As long as I don't change the content the cached copy stays on the client until it expires or they clear their temp files.  When I make a change the old version is discarded and a new hash is created.  When the client visits again their file is now invalid and it redownloads the new file.

I personally have not tried to create specific bundles but with a search I found someone who has created a custom bundle, I think this may be along the lines of what you are trying to accomplish: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389545/ASP-NET-MVC4-Bundling-and-Minification